# Curious one time connection error (MongoDB) on Travis CI for first test case only

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, continuous-integration, authorization, travis-ci

tl;dr

Tests pass locally, but on Travis CI the very first test case (order of tests is random) always fails. What could be the cause?

***Do you know how I can pinpoint where the error is?***

---

Some info:

- Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) locally / Ubuntu Precise (12.04) on Travis-CI
- Ruby 2.2.0
- Rails 4.2.5
- Mongoid 5.0.1
- MongoDB 3.0.8 locally and on Travis-CI
- *feel free to ask anything of interest*

---

Whenever I **test locally** on my development machine, all tests pass **successfully**. Example:

**Local Repo:**

```
[user]@[machine]:~/ComeMalaka$ rake test Run options: --seed 7888

# Running:

.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Finished in 94.316005s, 2.3008 runs/s, 32.2533 assertions/s.

217 runs, 3042 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips Coverage report generated for MiniTest to /home/elyasin/ComeMalaka/coverage. 362 / 362 LOC (100.0%) covered.
[user]@[machine]:~/ComeMalaka$
```

---

On my Travis CI build however **only the very first test case always fails** with an error and **all the other test cases pass**. The test cases are executed in random order, so **every time the first test case is a different one**. **But** every time the first test case **fails with the same error message (Mongo driver mentions authorization error)**.
I am not able to understand why and I don't have an idea what it could be or how to dig deeper.

**Travis-CI builds:**

```
# Running:

E........................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Finished in 101.320161s, 2.1417 runs/s, 30.0138 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
ApplicationControllerTest#test_after_sign_in_path:
Mongo::Auth::Unauthorized: User tester is not authorized to access come_malaka_test.
    test/test_helper.rb:33:in `setup'
    test/controllers/application_controller_test.rb:9:in `setup'

217 runs, 3041 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips



# Running:

E........................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Finished in 79.807236s, 2.7191 runs/s, 38.0793 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
EventRoutesTest#test_must_route_to_expense_report:
Mongo::Auth::Unauthorized: User tester is not authorized to access come_malaka_test.
    test/test_helper.rb:33:in `setup'

217 runs, 3039 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why exactly the problem happened, but I managed to fix it. Since the error message said it was due to authorization. I changed my `.travis.yml` file and created the test user with roles before starting the tests, e.g.:

```
- mongo come_malaka_test --eval "db.createUser({user:'user',pwd:'pwd',roles:['readWrite']});"
```

Since then, I did not have the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem while using Ansible to provision a Trusty box with Mongo - I was getting authorization error on the first connection to Mongo while trying to setup my database.

What helped in my case was to add to my playbook a sleep command (for 30s) just before the setup (and after its installation).

I read about it here: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1967

Comment: Thank you Antash. I used the sleep command already and changing times did not help really. My solution is in my answer, though I still don't know why that happens/happened.